# use sqlite with mac os x app using swift programming language

Tags: xcode, macos, sqlite

hi I have found this site
http://www.theappguruz.com/tutorial/use-sqlite-database-swift/
but I don't  understand step 5 and 6 what is the Add Bridging Header
please help

Comment: And googling for "swift language bridging header" provided no hits?

Comment: I cant understand the results

Answer (score 2):

create a new ios touch class, when prompted select objective C as language.  call it temporary and create.  you will be prompted to create a bridge header, say yes.  then delete the temporary .h and .m